# Cucumber for Web testing: better Ruby or JRuby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, jruby

I need to set up the automation framework of a Web project using cucumber and researching about the subject I see people who're using Ruby and others who are using JRuby, but I cannot see any article or explanation about what's the difference between the two in his context.

Any idea which one I should go for and why it could be better that one?

Comment: does your web project have a serverside component using either java or ruby? If not then the choice probably doesn't matter that much as you will ot be reusing stuff, but jruby might be a bit easier to setup depending upon OS choice.

Comment: I would go for the same stack as the web application is written in. This will allow developers to be able to chip in with writing tests as well. Or help anyone stuck on a language issue.

Answer (score 0):

[`cucumber`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber) is a language-agnostic, behavior-driven testing tool.  It allows stakeholders to create human-readable product specifications that also serve as executable test scenarios.  So--relative to the tool--cucumber doesn't care what language you are using.

The difference between `ruby` and `jruby` is that [`jruby`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/AboutJRuby) is an implementation of the `ruby` language in `Java`.

Comment: And regarding the language, is there any advantage of one over the other, eg, related to gems available, community support, widely used, debugging, etc? I've not been able to find why some people use Ruby whereas others use JRuby for a similar test framework...

Comment: Which language is right for you?  That depends on the stack of the application under test, what you're testing (e.g. UI, API, etc.), and what tool you are using for testing.  Beyond that, I'd just be offering something opinion-based.

Comment: For your gems question : https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives. Jruby gives you access to java libraries but looses C extension gems. From automation standpoint, you dont tend to lose or gain much by changing the language. There are also alternate gems available.

Its a more critical aspect when you are building an app.



An older thread: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/193471